# Active focus hover : keep parent focus hover when go to sub menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

L'm making navigation menu using bootstrap, I want to keep parent focus hovers while louse focus to submenu 
This is my code

```
.nav-horizontal > li {
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 2px;
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #535152;
}
.nav-horizontal > li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
.nav-horizontal > li > a {
    border-radius: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;  
    color: #231f20;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
.nav-horizontal > li + li {
    margin-left: 2px;
}
.nav-horizontal > li.active > a,
.nav-horizontal > li.active > a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.nav-horizontal > li:hover > a > a {
    background: #373435;
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

I have changed but it still can't focus parent hovered. How to fix its?

Comment: Can you clarify? Focus / hover are not tightly coupled. Note, only a single element can have focus, hovering another does not remove focus, focusing another does. Additionally, hovering a child maintains the hover state of the parent. If you can add a small working example, it may help illustrate more clearly :S

Comment: See this [link](http://artnice.lussa.net) . So I want to keep a hover font color when mouse over to submenu

Answer (score 0):

Try this following structure

```
 .nav-horizontal ul li:hover > a {
    background: #373435;
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
```